# Anchor Deploy Error

Tags: anchor, deploy

By Deploying Anchor with command: anchor deploy I get this error:

```
Error: Unable to open program file: No such file or directory (os error 2)
There was a problem deploying: Output { status: ExitStatus(unix_wait_status(256)), stdout: "", stderr: "" }
```

I tried a lot, but still can fix it - someone an idea?

Comment: I get this Error by the command solana validator: root@LAPTOP-91130O65:~/solana/poi# solana-test-validator
Error: Unable to lock test-ledger directory. Check if another validator is running I got a tap open since 3 hours with this command: WebSocket PubSub URL: ws://127.0.0.1:8900
⠒ 00:02:46 | Processed Slot: 238 | Confirmed Slot: 238 | Finalized Slot: 206 | Full Snapshot Slot: 200 | Incremental Snapshot Slot: - | Transactions
⠒ 00:02:46 | Processed Slot: 238 | Confirmed Slot: 238 | Finalized Slot: 206 | Full Snapshot Slot: 200 | Incremental Snapshot Slot: - | Transactions
⠲ 00:02:46 | Process

Comment: Please create a new question for the new comment

Answer (score 1):

maybe you are trying to deploy to local cluster but your local validator is not running?

You can start it with

```
solana-test-validator
```

in the terminal.

Check your anchor.toml file you can also change the target to devnet there.

Answer (score 0):

"I get this Error by the command solana validator:

root@LAPTOP-91130O65:~/solana/poi# solana-test-validator Error: Unable to lock test-ledger directory. Check if another validator is running"

You are getting this error because you already have the test-ledger folder with the previous validator files, in order to run a new one and fix that error, you need to delete the files and write solana-test-validator again.

Regarding your second question it will not finish, because basically you are running your own validator locally.

When testing you can use the Anchor test --skip-local-validator to test your program.

Comment: Let's add this answer when the original poster makes an additional question

Comment: How can I delete the files and write it again? I tried by "kill" the terminal and start it new with solana-test-validator, but it still going on to load some files since yesterday: ⠐ 00:01:50 | Processed Slot: 10524 | Confirmed Slot: 10524 | Finalized Slot: 10492 | Full Snapshot Slot: 10400 | Incremental Snapshot Slot: - | Transa

Comment: @LastUnicorn You can delete the test-folder manually .